# Is it possible to add a gvSIG document on Html?And if yes, how?

Tags: ms-access, web, gvsig

I have completed a project in gvSIG and now I would like to be able to open it from my webpage, like a hyperlink or path or something.Can I really do that somehow? And if yes, could you please explain how?

Thanks a lot.

Eva

Answer (score 2):

Sorry, Eva, but that is not possible in a *easy* way: gvSIG is a desktop software, so it has no webs service to share your project or views.

On the other hand, I can advise you some solutions depending on what you really need:

1. Static information: Export your views as image or PDF.
2. Share a layer: You can export your layer as KML and [load it in google Maps](https://developers.google.com/kml/articles/pagesforkml) or other service like this or include it in your page use Google Map JS api
3. Share a layer composition: Install on a server your own map server (like MapSever, GeoServer, etc) and publish your maps using a JavaScript library (like OpenLayer or Leaflet).

Good luck!